# Access Function Builder in Query builder return nothing

Tags: sql, function, ms-access

i am running a complex calculation through update query, i managed to get all other work done however am struggling to get this bit done. i use function builder window to set the update fo field for the targeted field. My table is as following:

| PHD_TAG | Cal_Value | Moisture | CO2_EF | CO2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 100 | 0.5 | 0.45 | * |
| FAC1 | 20 |  |  |  |
| FAC2 | 7 |  |  |  |

My function is to calculate and update the CO2 Field with a *

```
(1-((DLookup("Cal_Value", "TempTbl", "PHD_TAG = 'FAC1'"))+[Moisture])/100)*(DLookup("Cal_Value", "TempTbl", "PHD_TAG = 'FAC2'"))*[CO2_EF]/(22.4*44*24)
```

the query generated in query builder "SQL Query" is as following:

```
UPDATE TempTbl SET TempTbl.CO2 = (1-((DLookUp("Cal_Value","TempTbl","PHD_TAG = 'FAC1'"))+[Moisture])/100)*(DLookUp("Cal_Value","TempTbl","PHD_TAG = 'FAC2'"))*[CO2_EF]/(22.4*44*24)
WHERE (((TempTbl.PHD_TAG)="ABC"));
```

Comment: What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing? Are FAC1 and FAC2 unique values? Why save calculated value and not just do calculation when needed? This is an odd requirement - why is CO2 in ABC record dependent on FAC1 and FAC2 records and why are fields empty in FAC1 and FAC2?

Comment: What number type is "CO2"? When you run the function with the data supplied, the answer is 1.05868252840909E-04, so depending on the number type used in the table, it may be updating it to 0.

Comment: FAC1 and FAC1 are combination of numbers and letters consider them special identifier for each equipment, and different equipment has a different calculation method for CO2.

Comment: when i run the code above no result is shown

Answer (score 0):

i had the PHDTAG wrong and fixed it then i had to change the brackets to perform the proper mathematical calculation.

the expression used is correct just the PHD_TAG was wrong and the brackets in formula